# Exporting a singe function from loadash contributes 100KB in the final build - Why is that?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, build, lodash, create-react-app

In my whole application, the only function I am using from loadash is `deepClone`. The import that I make across several files is just this:

```
import {cloneDeep} from "lodash";
```

Even then the contribution of lodash to the entire build is `102.1KB` as deduced from [the source map explorer](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/analyzing-the-bundle-size/) using the command `source-map-explorer 'build/static/js/*.js`

Here is what it shows

[image]

Why is that? How could I reduce it?

Comment: Lodash out of the box has some issues with tree-shaking. Not diving into details, you can try 1. lodash-es (basically a custom build of lodash) 2. Different import syntax. Something like import cloneDeep from 'lodash/cloneDeep". 3. Babel plugin which does item №2. automatically, can't recall the name. Keywords to search: "lodash tree shaking"

Comment: According to issues with tree-shaking, you could use JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data))